# MySQL syntax error: unexpected 'unique'

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have the following query:

```
select u.UserName, count(*) as total 
from Voting v join User u using (UserID)
where unique (select s.AlbumID, s.Number from Song s where s.AlbumID=v.AlbumID and s.Number=v.Number)
group by u.UserName
order by total desc;
```

This is supposed to do the following: for each user, display the username and number of songs the user has voted on. Without the `where unique (...)` line this works fine, but I want votes on the same song **not to be counted** as multiple votes, and I'm not really sure how to do this, because that line produces a syntax error (and my textbook says you can do it like that :-)).

The schema looks like this:

```
table Album(AlbumID(PK), AlbumName)

table Song((Number,AlbumID)(PK), SongName)

table User(UserID(PK), UserName)

table Voting((UserID,AlbumID,Number)(PK),Vote,Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to count the distinct numbers in the album the user has voted on. To do this, join the songs table as well.

The only thing unclear is, how would you know if a user has voted on a song? Is vote a `yes/no` column? If so, you might have to change the aggregation.

```
select u.UserName, count(distinct v.Number) as total 
--count(distinct case when v.vote = 'yes' then 1 end) as total
--use this if vote is a yes/no column.
from Voting v
join `User` u on u.userid=v.userid
join Song s on s.AlbumID=v.AlbumID and s.Number=v.Number
group by u.UserName
order by total desc
```

Comment: But, in my case, a song is defined by both AlbumID and the Number on that album. If I understood it correctly, this doesn't count votes on songs with the same number on different albums. Can I use *distinct* for both AlbumID and Number? Something like *count (distinct v.Number, v.AlbumID)*? p.s. *Vote* is a number :)

Comment: can you post some sample data or set up a sql fiddle? using `count (distinct v.Number, v.AlbumID)` is not valid.

Comment: Actually I realized that a user **can't** vote for the same song multiple times because of the PK in *Voting* :D So I guess I don't have a problem. But still, you helped with the *count(distinct...)*.